# Django call_command() with filename wildcard

Tags: python, django

How can you use filename wildcards in `call_command()`? I'm trying to create a management command that does the same as `python manage.py loaddata */fixtures/*.json`

Below code throws `CommandError: No fixture named '*' found.`

```
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Load all fixtures in app directories'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        call_command('loaddata', '*/fixtures/*.json')
        self.stdout.write('Fixtures loaded\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glob input in `python manage.py loaddata */fixtures/*.json` command works because the glob is expanded by bash; if you try escaping the glob, e.g. `python manage.py loaddata '*/fixtures/*.json'`, the command should fail with the same error message.

Instead, expand the globs on Python side, for example:

```
import pathlib

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Load all fixtures in app directories'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cmd_args = list(pathlib.Path().glob('*/fixtures/*.json'))
        call_command('loaddata', *cmd_args)
```